# JavaScript functioning automatically, not "on click"

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I want to add a "show more" button to my website using Javascript.

Here is the HTML I am using

```
<div class="VideoText" align="left">
    <a href=""><span> <strong> Credits </strong> </span></a>
    <br> Directed By: <a href="http://www.kingdombrand.com/Film/Alek/Portfolio"> Link One </a>
    <br> Edited By: <a href="http://www.kingdombrand.com/Film/Jess/Portfolio"> Link Two </a>
    <br>
    <br>

    <a href="#" id="hideshow">Hide</a>

    <div id="message">
        Credit: <a href="http://www.kingdombrand.com/Film/Alek/Portfolio"> Link Three </a>
        <br> Credit: <a href="http://www.kingdombrand.com/Film/Alek/Portfolio"> Link Four </a>
        <br>
    </div>

</div>
```

and here is the .js file I am using to call the function

```
    $('#hideshow') .toggle(function() {
    $('#hideshow').text('Hide');
    $('#message').hide();

}, function() {

    $('#hideshow').text('Show') ;
    $('#message').Show();
}) ;
```

I am following a Youtube tutorial, however his seems to work fine. When I go to the site I am adding it to (http://www.kingdombrand.com/Film/Alek/Films/TestFilm) the words "Show Less" appear for a split second then dissapear off screen. What is it that I am doing wrong? I want to make the div dissapear, and re-apear when I select Hide/show